# Does Corda has the ability to integrate with some existing cryptocurrency

Tags: corda

Our business is interesting about whether we can integrate an existing cryptocurrency such as Ripple to CorDapp, so we can use Ripple as the payment currency for our CorDapp, does it possible to do?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509175/exchanging-corda-cash-states-for-traditional-cash.

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks for your sample approach, but that requires involve a traditional bank, do we have an example approach to integrate with one exiting 3rd part's cryptocurrency in CorDapp, such as Ripple, Bitcoin, etc?

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is documented here: [Exchanging Corda cash states for traditional cash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509175/exchanging-corda-cash-states-for-traditional-cash).

The only way to achieve this is to have a trusted party hold the cryptocurrency in escrow in the real-world, and issue corresponding on-ledger cryptocurrency states. At a later date, nodes can return the cryptocurrency states they hold to the escrow, who exits the states in exchange for real-world cash.